# Spring Boot- Profile setting Through YML file is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

In Spring Boot program, profile setting using application.yml is not working whereas the same program is working using applicaiton.properties. the following actions has been performed but it ended up in vain

1. In Eclipse ide Project-Clean has been done
2. Maven project updated
3. Spaces in YML file removed and corrected
4. YML file is deleted and recreated.

applicaiton.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: dev
```

applicaiton-dev.yml

```
spring: 
 datasource:
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   url: jdbc:mysql:///ntspbms616db
   username: root
   password: root
   dbcp2:
   max-total: 100
   initial-size: 10
   max-conn-lifetime-millis: 10000000
   type:  org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

The error i got after running the program is

```
Enter the Employee Name 
Raja
Enter the Employee  Designation
Manager
Enter the Basic Salary
9898999
12:28:40.622 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 4, column 2:
```

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error means literally what is says.

The "tab" is not permitted by the YAML specs:

> To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in
> indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently. Note that
> most modern editors may be configured so that pressing the tab key
> results in the insertion of an appropriate number of spaces.

So, you should double check for the tab characters in your yaml files and if exist, replace them by double space.

Also, just to add, I can see incorrect formatting of `dbcp2` section, without any intendation, so, it should look like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql:///ntspbms616db
    username: root
    password: root
    dbcp2:
      max-total: 100
      initial-size: 10
      max-conn-lifetime-millis: 10000000
    type: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Even after correcting the indentation the problem remains same.

Comment: After performing project clean in IDE,             
 i get this error.  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field empDAO in com.nt.service.EmployeeMgmtServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.nt.dao.IEmployeeDAO' that could not be found.

Comment: @Service("empService")
public class EmployeeMgmtServiceImpl implements IEmployeeMgmtService {
 @Autowired
 private IEmployeeDAO empDAO;